# add new row in table control by css

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp

How can i add new column by using html dom /css to control ?i have an idea but i dont know how to write the code, example now i have 4 columns and 20 rows, i want to display 2 as default row, and hidden the rest of 18. when click on add column button it will visible extra 1 row(based on how many time the button is clicked.

```
<script>
function fnUpdateColumn(value)
{
  document.mainform.submit();
}
</script>
<form name="mainform" action="test.jsp" method="post">
<tr><td>NAME</td><td>DOB</td><td>GENDER</td><td>AGE</td></tr>
<%for(int i =0;i<20;i++){ %>
<tr>
    <%for(int j =0;j<4;j++){ %>
        <td><input  type="text"name="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>"></td>
    <%}%>
</tr>
<%}%>
<input type="button" value="Add Column" onclick="fnUpdateColumn('addColumn');"> 
</form>
```

something like this my output
[image]
how do i perform the method in test.jsp ?

Comment: and than what after 20 rows

Comment: perhaps only max it for 20

Comment: Heyt, you mean while clicking "Add Column" button one new "Row" visible ?

Comment: please use proper terminology, instead of word column use row word then it would be easy for all to undersood.

Comment: ya... as from the screen design you can see there is 4 rows for current, how can i display a "hidden" row to "visible" when click on add column .. i have no idea how to set the row as "hidden" as well ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form name="mainform" action="test.jsp" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="temp"/>
<tr><td>NAME</td><td>DOB</td><td>GENDER</td><td>AGE</td></tr>
<%for(int i =0;i<20;i++){
if (i<2){ %>
<tr>
<td><input  type="text"name="NAME_<%=i %>"></td>
</tr>
<%} else {%>
<div id="row_<%=i%>" style="display:none;">
<td><input  type="text"name="NAME_<%=i %>"></td>
</div>
<%}%>
<%}%>
<input type="button" value="Add Column" onclick="showRow();"> 
</form>

<script>
function showRow() {
var temp;    
if (document.getElementById("temp").value == "") {
temp = 2;
} else {
temp = document.getElementById("temp").value;
}
document.getElementById("row_"+temp).style.display = "inline-block";
if (temp<20) {
document.getElementById("temp").value = temp+1;
}
}
</script>
```

This is an example how you can proceed:

**1)** Make a hidden input which will save your current hidden row, at first it is initialized with a blank value.

**2)** Iterate over the rows, if the current row is less than 2, which means these are first two rows to display, otherwise the next rows are placed inside a hidden div.

**3)** Make a javascript function which will be fired on the click button event. First it is checking the hidden value to see if it has a value different than initial blank value. If it is blank, that means the button was not clicked, and we initialize it with 2 (the third field's id), otherwise we are getting the value from the hidden field. After this, we are modifying the next hidden div value to display it. After we are checking if not the limit of the iteration was reached. If not, we are incrementing the value of the temp value and setting it to the hidden field.

Hope this works, i've not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete solution, just copy and paste into your JSP file,

**Note: add jqueryXXX.js file into your project.**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


<body>
hello

<table>

<tr><td>NAME</td><td>DOB</td><td>GENDER</td><td>AGE</td></tr>
<%for(int i =0;i<20;i++){ 
    if(i < 2){ %>
    <tr>
    <% }else{ %>
<tr id="<%=i+"_row"%>" style="display:none;" >  
    <%}%>

    <%for(int j =0;j<4;j++){%>
        <td><input  type="text"name="<%=j%>_NAME_<%=i %>"></td>
     <%}%>
</tr>
<%}%>

<input type="button" id="addNewRecord" value="Add New Column"/>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var nextShowValue = 2;
    $( "#addNewRecord" ).click(function() {

        $('#'+nextShowValue+'_row').show();

        if(nextShowValue < 21){
            nextShowValue++;    
        }else{
            alert('no more available rows')
        }


    });

});



</script>


</body>
</html>
```